# How do I require one field to be (A and B), or ( A), or (B), or (A and C), or (C)

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I'm having trouble coming up with a schema that can accommodate these scenarios:

- This field can have **A**, and/or only one of **B or C**
- This field can have only **A**
- This field can have only one of **B** or one of **C**

A, B and C have the same schema.

Basically B and C can not exist simultaneously.

**Example scenarios:**

```
// Valid
{
    "exampleItem": {
        "A": [{
            "key": "item A",
            "description": "test desc"
        }],
        "B": [{
            "key": "item B",
            "description": "test desc"
        }]
    }
}

// Invalid
{
    "exampleItem": {
        "B": [{
            "key": "item B",
            "description": "test desc"
        }],
        "C": [{
            "key": "item C",
            "description": "test desc"
        }]
    }
}
```

**What I've tried:**

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "definitions": {
        "exampleItemSchema": {
            "type": "object",
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": { 
                        "A": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "required": [ "key", "description" ],
                                "properties": {
                                    "key": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "description": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }

                                }
                            }                            
                        },
                        "B": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "required": [ "key", "description" ],
                                "properties": {
                                    "key": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "description": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }

                                }
                            }                            
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": { 
                        "A": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "required": [ "key", "description" ],
                                "properties": {
                                    "key": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "description": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }

                                }
                            }                            
                        },
                        "C": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "required": [ "key", "description" ],
                                "properties": {
                                    "key": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "description": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }

                                }
                            }                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
    
}
```

I'm using `oneOf` right now, but I'm quite certain it's not what I want. I can't use `anyOf` because I don't want B and C to exist together, and `allOf` would assert against A, B and C.

Comment: Are you aware of the `not` keyword in JSON Schema? You can do `not` > `required: B,C`. Sorry on mobile currently. Can form an answer later.

Answer (score 0):

To assert that a property can *not* exist, you can either do:

```
{
  "not": {
    "required": [
      "property name"
    ]
  }
}
```

or:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "property name": false
  }
}
```

You can assert that a property *must* exist with the `required` keyword.

You can combine schemas together with `allOf`, `anyOf`, and `oneOf`.

Remember that subschemas are not just used to influence the overall result, but can be used as pre-conditions for another subschema to be evaluated, and *that* subschema will form part of the overall evaluation results.  The keywords `not`, and `if`/`then`/`else` use preconditions to decide how they will evaluate.  The conditions in a `not` and `if` are only used to determine a true/false result, and nothing else asserted in those subschemas will be used in the final result.

This should be all the tools in the toolbox that you need.

(For readability, I would keep all the `properties` keywords (that define what A, B and C should look like, should they exist and are permitted) at the top layer, and then use sub-assertions with if/then/else and not just to state which properties must or must not exist, and in what combinations.)